# how to do breeze custom saveChanges to an api controller with class object

Tags: breeze

My breeze api controller is like this

```
public HttpResponseMessage CreateUser(class object)
{}
```

I have a separate Unit of Work to Savechanges() done by breeze..

I need to pass my json to `class object` not as `Jobject`

Here is my breeze `savechanges()`

```
var signupDetail = manager.getEntities(entityNames.userdetail);
var resourceDetail = new breeze.SaveOptions({
    resourceName: "CreateUser"
});
return manager.saveChanges(signupDetail, resourseDetail)
```

Where it sends json as  Jobject savebundle with "entities[] and key mappings[]"
done by "breeze-debug.js"

But i need it as "string json"  for my class object

Is there any solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the SaveChanges method of the Context directly, your question doesn't have too much details but I will venture to make some assumptions and try to answer it as today I got a similar problem.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    // ...
}

public class MyRepository
{
    private readonly EFContextProvider<MyContext> _contextProvider;

    public MyRepository()
    {
        _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<MyContext>();
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        // Save all changes made in this context to the underlying database
        // this is the method you should call
        _contextProvider.Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }
}
```

And then you can use something like this in your controller:

```
[BreezeController]
public class TaskController : ApiController
{
    private readonly MyRepository _repository;

    public TaskController()
    {
        _repository = new MyRepository();
    }

    public void CreateUser(string className)
    {
        // Create the target object
        // ...

        // Call save changes
        _repository.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.